# dotnet nuget push gives 401, but nuget.exe push succeeds

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget

I've created a feed in Azure Artifacts, to which I want to publish Nuget packages.
I have generated a Personal Access Token with the correct scope.

Running this command succeeds:

```
> nuget.exe  push -Source "myAzureFeed" -Apikey $(cat apikey) .\bin\Debug/MyPackage1.2.3.nupkg
```

Whereas, this command:

```
> dotnet nuget push .\bin\Debug\MyPackage.1.2.3.nupkg -s "myAzureFeed" -k $(cat apikey)
```

Gives me 401

```
PS D:\NuGet\create-package\using-dotnet-cli> dotnet nuget push .\bin\Debug\MyPackage.1.2.3.nupkg -s myAzureFeed -k $(cat apikey)
Pushing MyPackage.1.2.3.nupkg to 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/123/abc/_packaging/xyz/v2/'...
  PUT https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/123/abc/_packaging/xyz/nuget/v2/
  Unauthorized https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/123/abc/_packaging/xyz/v2/'...
  PUT https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/123/abc/_packaging/xyz/nuget/v2/ 1323ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Why does `nuget.exe push` succeeds and `dotnet nuget push` fails?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does nuget.exe push succeeds and dotnet nuget push fails?

There's already a [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7792#issuecomment-556978260) talking about this. See JeremyTCD's comment:

> --api-key works for some feeds (e.g Nuget.org) but not for others (e.g Azure Artifacts feeds). For the latter kind of feed you need to
> specify password. Unfortunately password isn't accepted by the dotnet
> nuget or nuget CLIs so you have to set it in a nuget.config. Easiest
> way to update nuget.config is nuget sources add ....

The dotnet nuget push command pushes a package to the server and publishes it. The push command uses server and credential details found in the system's `NuGet config file` or chain of config files. See [dotnet nuget push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push) for details.

So, before using the `dotnet nuget push` command, you should add the credential and API key in `NuGet.config` as below commands:

```
nuget sources Add -Name "mysource" -Source "https://XXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YYY/nuget/v3/index.json" -username name -password PAT nuget setapikey mykey -source mysource
```

Then push the NuGet package through the dotnet nuget push command:

```
dotnet nuget push packagename.nupkg --source mysource --api-key mykey
```

You can also reference the samples instructed here: [Publish packages from external sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/dotnet-exe?view=azure-devops#publish-packages-from-external-sources) to do that by running `dotnet nuget`comamnds.

Comment: thanks. But the delta is between using nuget.exe push and dotnet.exe nuget push, both with the `--api-key/-k`  option. The former succeeds, while the latter fails.  By the way, since you mentioned it, what is meant by  "external sources" in "Publish packages from external sources" mean?

Comment: @YoavKlein Yeah, that's the [Github issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7792#issuecomment-556978260) talking about. "`external sources`" means the sources out of Azure Artifacts, for example local feeds, or other third-party feeds.